# Как создать массив объектов первого класса во втором классе

Tags: c#, массивы, классы, наследование

Два класса:
Первый класс (Товар) содержит в себе 3 закрытых поля (название, номер, время)(строкового типа), под них создаются 3 свойства для доступа из другого класса. Так же в этом классе есть метод для ввода этих трёх переменных.
Второй класс (Склад) содержит закрытый массив объектов (Товаров). Есть метод для ввода кол-во объектов (Товаров)(определяет какое количество объектов будет содержать массив и соответственно сколько объектов будет создано (классная логика)).

```
class Tovar
{
    private string nazvanie;
    private string numberP;
    private string time;

    public string Nazvnanie { get { return nazvanie; } set { nazvanie = value; } }
    public string NumberP { get { return numberP; } set { numberP = value; } }
    public string Time { get { return time; } set { time = value; } }

    public void InputP()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите название товара: ");
        nazvanie = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Введите номер товара: ");
        numberP = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Введите время комплектации товара в формате (xx:xx) : ");
        time = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Ниже метод второго класса у которого присутствует проблема присвоения значений введённых в методе выше. Как можно исправить эту проблему?

```
private static int nTovar;
private Tovar[] tovar = new Tovar[nTovar];
public void InfTovar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nTovar; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Введите данные о {i+1} товаре:");
            InputP();
            tovar[i].Nazvnanie = Nazvnanie;
            tovar[i].NumberP = NumberP;
            tovar[i].Time = Time;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private Tovar[] tovar;

public void InfTovar()
{
    Console.Write("Введите количество товаров: ");
    int nTovar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    tovar = new Tovar[nTovar];
    for (int i = 0; i < tovar.Length; ++i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Введите данные о {i+1} товаре:");
        tovar[i] = new Tovar();
        tovar[i].InputP();
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Ещё привыкать и привыкать работать с классами и массивами.